# Google play support 0 devices

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, device

I am trying  put  app at google console but when i load the APK it support 0 devices. I tried so many ways but it dont load the devices as you can see in pictures. Above is my Manifest and Gradle

[image: devices]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appspocket.hooop"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Comment: "Above is my Manifest and Gradle" where is manifest?

Comment: I am trying to put the code but they are not accepting the format ı dont know why. ı wıll put a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.appspocket.hooop.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup">

    <activity
        android:name="com.appspocket.hooop.VideoItemListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.appspocket.hooop.VideoItemDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_videoitem_detail"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.appspocket.hooop.VideoItemListActivity" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="youtube.com" />
            <data android:host="m.youtube.com" />
            <data android:host="www.youtube.com" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/v/" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/watch" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/attribution_link" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="youtu.be" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="vnd.youtube" />
            <data android:scheme="vnd.youtube.launch" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.appspocket.hooop.player.PlayVideoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/VideoPlayerTheme"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

    <service
        android:name="com.appspocket.hooop.player.BackgroundPlayer"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/background_player_name" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.appspocket.hooop.player.ExoPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/PlayerTheme">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.appspocket.Hooop_Dinle.exoplayer.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:scheme="asset" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.appspocket.hooop.player.BackgroundPlayer"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/background_player_name" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.appspocket.hooop.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/settings_activity_title" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.appspocket.hooop.PanicResponderActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="info.guardianproject.panic.action.TRIGGER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.appspocket.hooop.ExitActivity"
        android:label="@string/general_error"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
    <activity android:name="com.appspocket.hooop.ErrorActivity" />
</application>
```